# pycharm regex replace string and keep the original matched ones

Tags: regex, pycharm

In a .py file there are many concatenated sql queries.
Which contains

```sql
and a.created_at >='2019-01-01'
...
and b.deleted_at >='2019-01-01'
...
and c.received_at >='2019-01-01'
```

Now I want to comment out these time comparisons codes, make them toke

```sql
-- and a.created_at >='2019-01-01'
...
-- and b.deleted_at >='2019-01-01'
...
-- and c.received_at >='2019-01-01'
```

I can use `and (.*?) >='2019-01-01'` to match these comparisons.

How could add `--` in the replacement?

Comment: You have an accepted answer to your question.  If you have another question to ask, then feel free to ask a new one.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks, I have just figured this out with googling!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `$0` in the replacement, which should correspond to the entire matched line:

```
Find:    ^and .* >='2019-01-01'$
Replace: -- $0
```

I don't know PyCharm well, and the `^ $` anchors in the pattern might not even be necessary, if the default behavior be to match to the entire input line.  But, they should not be wrong there, either.

Comment: What if I want to replace it reverse?  `-- and c.received_at >='2019-01-01'` to `and c.received_at >='2019-01-01'` (multi lines).

Comment: You should ask this in a new question.